# Sorting multiset as ascending subsequences with one occurence of each available element

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, sorting, set

Let's assume given multiset, e.g.

```
A = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}.
```

What is the easiest way to sort elements like that:

```
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3),
```

i.e. a sequence built from ascending subsequences built from available elements of the set?

How to achieve in both C++ and Python. Are there any libraries for that? How to do it "by hand"?

Comment: Will this always be sorting numerically or will your multiset occasionally hold non-numericals? Similarly, will you always have a set number of each digit or will they vary as well?

Finally, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I need it beacuse I regard it as useful to one of exercises. It is not from any kind of school. There will be only digits.

Comment: I think you need to specify more constraints. E.g. any sequence can be trivially separated into ascending subsequences - where all subsequences have length 1. But presumably that's not what you want? Also, what's the answer for the multiset `B = { 2, 2 }`?

Comment: I'd like to use as many elements as possible in each subsequence. For {2,2} it's just (2,2)

Comment: If you may use a second container when it is not difficult to rewrite elements of the set into the second container in the order you specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement that as a [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)
First you count how many times each element occurs, element being the index in the array that stores the number of occurrences of each value.  Then loop through that array, until each index has a value zero.

This might not the best(or most efficient) way to implement it, but this is the solution that first comes to mind.

Comment: Python seems to have a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) class to do the counting for you.  (Beware, it doesn't appear to sort the keys in the manner you might expect.)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I was thinking more about c++, but cool :) 
That could definitely be used in this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're willing to modify your original multiset, (or work on a copy of it), do something like

```
while(!data.empty()) {
    auto x = data.begin();
    while( x != data.end()) {
        auto value = *x;
        cout << value << endl;
        data.erase(x); // delete *one* item
        x = data.upper_bound(value); // find the next *different* value
    }
}
```

This isn't very efficient.  If you have a huge dataset, then maybe you need to think about what your constraints are (memory or time?).

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.group)  to get a matrix of the unique groups of items from a sorted list:

```
from itertools import groupby, izip_longest

A=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

groups=[]
for k, g in groupby(sorted(A)):
    groups.append(list(g))

print groups
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

More succinctly, you can use a list comprehension to do the same thing:

```
groups=[list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(A))]
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Or, you can expand the Python version of a multiset, [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and sort the keys to get this same nested list:

```
from collections import Counter
c=Counter(A)
groups=[[k]*c[k] for k in sorted(c.keys())]
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Once you have the nested lists `groups`, invert the matrix using [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), flatten the lists, and delete the `None` values:

```
print [e for t in izip_longest(*groups) for e in t if e!=None]
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Why not just list-comprehend the groups construction? `[list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(A))]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do by hand in python without any imported libraries:

```
A = (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)

# create a list out of a set of unique elems in A
a = list(set(A))
a.sort() # sort so they are in ascending order

countList = []

# find how many repeated elems in the list set we just made
for i, elem in enumerate(a, 0):
    countList.append(A.count(elem))

# find the what is the lowest repeated number in the orig list
minEntry = min(countList)
# we can multiply the list set by that lowest number
outString = a * minEntry

# add the left over numbers to the outstring
for i in range(len(countList)):
    count = abs(countList[i] - minEntry)
    if count != 0:
        outString.append(a[i]*count)

print outString
```

and here is the outputString

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you may use a second sequantial container then in C++ you can simply move elements of the original container in the second container by means of standard algorithms std::unique_copy and std::set_difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Test(seq):
    index = 0
    Seq = seq
    newlist = []
    while len(Seq) != 0:
            newlist.append(list(set(Seq).union()))
            for Del in newlist[index]:
                    Seq.remove(Del)
            index += 1
    return [y for x in newlist for y in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

in C++, instead of manipulating data structures, you could prepare a list of iterators to the beginnings of the equal ranges, and then dereference/increment those iterators in turn:

```
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::multiset<int> A = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3};

    // build a list of iterator pairs to each equal range
    std::list< std::pair<std::multiset<int>::iterator,
                         std::multiset<int>::iterator> > iters;
    for(auto it=A.begin(); it != A.end(); it = A.upper_bound(*it))
        iters.push_back(A.equal_range(*it));

    // for each non-empty subrange, show what the first iterator is
    // pointing to, then advance it by one position in its subrange
    // if the subrange is empty, drop it from the list
    while(!iters.empty())
        for(auto it = iters.begin(); it != iters.end(); )
            if(it->first != it->second)
               std::cout << *it++->first++ << ' '; // don't do this at home
            else
               it = iters.erase(it);
}
```